# Apolllo client-state preset cache does not work on server side render

Tags: next.js, react-apollo, apollo-client, server-side-rendering, react-ssr

I am trying to use Apollo client-state data with the hooks `useQuery` and `useMutation` as a global store inside a NextJS app.
When I follow the example from NextJS called `with-apollo` (https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo), which uses a HOC in which it runs all the queries and renders the app on the server first.

Normally, you want to catch the 'loading' state in a component like this:

```
const { loading, data } = useQuery(GET_NAME_QUERY) // some @client query
if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>
return <h1>Hello {data.name</h1>
```

But I want to skip the loading-check and always have a default state available. I think this could be done with setting the cache of the apollo-client to a set of default values, like this:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState);

// This is the part where the initial client-state data is set:
cache.writeData({
  data: { name: 'Harry' } 
});

const apolloClient =  new ApolloClient({
  cache,  // <-- cache with preset client-state data
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
})
```

With the goal to just do this:

```
const { data } = useQuery(GET_NAME_QUERY) // some @client query, resolves immediately from cache
return <h1>Hello {data.name</h1>
```

I created a repo with a robot and its name & status that are cached from the beginning this way. See https://github.com/rnacken/next-with-apollo-client-state-cache

The client works, without any errors, but during SSR, I get an error, since it does not have the data yet (and 'loading' is true) after a `useQuery` call.
When I log the loading/data state, I see this on the server:
[image: SSR error] 
On the client, it's all good:
[image: client]

Does anybody know how this is happening? With the cache set, I shouldn't see a loading:true state ever right? Is the `getDataFromTree` from `@apollo/react-ssr` not working correctly?

Comment: It seems there are more people with this issue and it might be a bug/feature in `react-apollo`: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3486